# What kind of maple is this?

Tags: identification, maple

The zone is 8a, Central Europe. The photo is taken mid-May.

[image]

[image]

The back side is little purplish:

[image]

Helicopters:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe *Acer opalus*

Comment: What part of the world?

Comment: Central Europe. @kevinsky

Comment: Judging from the leaf (second picture), my guess is [*Acer pseudoplatanus*](https://landscapeplants.oregonstate.edu/plants/acer-pseudoplatanus). Can't see the trunk and bark very good.